# For loop that will not fetch Thumbs.db files

Tags: batch-file

I want to create an script that will not fetch Thumbs.db file from a folder location.
I have created a script but when i am running the FOR loop , that Thumbs.DB file is also Visible in the list.

Here is the Relevant part of the script:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /a-d/b "%src_dir%*.*"') do ( echo %%G>> %save_file% )
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just check inside the loop?

```
FOR %%x IN (*.*) DO (
  IF NOT "%%x"=="Thumbs.DB" (
    ECHO %%x
  )
)
```

Comment: Here is the Relevant part of the script: 

for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /a-d/b "%src_dir%\*.*"') do  (
echo %%G>> %save_file% 
)

Comment: and it is including Thumbs.db  files. that i dont want to include into results

Comment: So that's what the IF can do. It can check if the file is Thumbs.DB and if so, don't process it. The for loop will still return that file, but you can skip it in the processing. So, basically like the code in my answer. Note that you might need to add some modifiers to make the comparison case-insensitive.

Comment: Yes It is working but it is also producing some unwanted messages like:
Access denied
File Not Found--Type
File Not Found- F
etc..

Comment: Is `%save_file%` set properly and pointing to a proper file (to which you have write/append access?

Comment: I apology  #Golez Trol.. I have appended the code wrongly, that's why I was getting those  errors. Now it is working accordingly.
Do you know, how to run Unix Commands In Batch Script.
If yes please let me know.

Comment: That sounds like a different question. Better to close this one and ask a new one, so you'll attract a new audience who might answer it for you. When do you, please be clear on what kind of commands you want to run.